# Custom Search Query – include only custom fields and title

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, search, post-meta

I have a custom post type and I also need a custom search. I want the post title and two custom fields to be indexed/queried. I found solutions for title only and for custom fields but not for both so I tried to combine. Why doesn't this work?

```
function custom_search( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    $searchand = ' OR ';
    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}(($wpdb->m.meta_key = 'wpcf-kurzbeschreibung') AND (m.meta_value  LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}'))";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'custom_search', 500, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use a custom query so I can just use:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'akteur', 'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array('key' => 'wpcf-kurzbeschreibung','compare' => 'LIKE','value' => $suchbegriff),
                                array('key' => 'wpcf-zusatzinfo','compare' => 'LIKE','value' => $suchbegriff)
                            )
                            ));
```